# How to show Progressbar in AsynkTask in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to show progreebar instead of progressdialog in onpreexecute and onpost execute while retreiving data from server.

This is my async method

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    m_ProgressBar = new ProgressBar(getActivity(), null, R.layout.progress_bar);
    m_ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
    m_ProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

where this progressbar is in progress_bar layout,which is seperate layout and this onPreecute method is in login class

Comment: search in google u will many solutions..

Answer (score 0):

```
Below code snippet uses will help you

private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,Void>{

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Saving image....");
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss").format(new Date());
        createDirectory();
        try {
            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+"/QuoteCards/IMG_"+timeStamp+".png"));
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
            // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        frameLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image has been saved in SD Card",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        scan();
    }

}
```

Comment: he asked ProgressBar not ProgressDialog

Comment: yes correct i m not asking for progressdialog i want progressbar instead of progressdialog

Comment: @abhishek - In that case you can add progressbar in your layout xml and set its visibility as GONE. Then in onPreExecute() you have to make it VISIBLE and in onPostExecute you have to make its visibility as GONE again.

Answer (score 0):

The normal template would be something like this

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
   protected void onPreExecute() {         
     progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
   }

   protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
     Bitmap = downloadImageFromUrl(strings[0]);
     return someBitmap;
   }

   protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... values) {
    progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);
   }  

   protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
     imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
     // Hide the progress bar
     progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is used is like this.. I created a separate diloag.xml and included the progress bar inside it..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text=""
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
    android:maxHeight="20dp"
    android:minHeight="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the in the java code on onCreate or onCreateView initialized the Dialog

```
    dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.prograss_bar_dialog);
```

and also write two functions like showPB() and hidePB()

```
   public void showPB(String message) {
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
    TextView progressText = (TextView)   dialog.findViewById(R.id.progress_text);
    progressText.setText("" + message);
    progressText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
    }


    public void hidePB() {
    //if (dialog != null) {
    dialog.dismiss();
     //}
    }
```

and call whenever u need and also be sure to call hidePB()

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks .............you give me correct solution

Comment: Then i deserve an upvote right ? :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all add ProgressBar view to layout

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

In MyAwesomeAsynkTaskClass initialize progress bar like

```
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
```

And modify onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() by the following steps:

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
}
```